# PHP Document Expired

Tags: php, back-button

I doing some PHP coding, if the 'Back' button is pressed on the browser, I get the following error:

```
Document Expired
This document is no longer available.
```

What code can I implement to cater to this situation

Comment: Do you use POST for searching? Easy answer: Don't.

Comment: are you trying to submit the form and then after a while pressing back button?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error - Web Page Has Expired in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987765/error-web-page-has-expired-in-php)

Comment: How do you want us to help you when there's no code, no method ?

Answer (score 27):

**Add this in the start of PHP codes**:

```
ini_set('session.cache_limiter','public');
session_cache_limiter(false);
```

Comment: Super easy fix to a relatively complex and troublesome issue, thanks!

Comment: This fixes the issue of having the "document expired" error, however, if I click on a link in a php web app that brings me to a table that has Post actions like rename and delete, If I click on rename then click cancel, the back button will put the table on rename mode rather than going to the previous page... Don't know how to fix that yet

Answer (score 19):

Set Cache-Control header in your main page.

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: max-age=900');
?>
```

Comment: This did not work for me but the solution offered by @tazo todua below did.

Answer (score 17):

**Using Post/Redirect/Get rule you can avoid this.**

This problem will arise by the following:

- Let say I have `example1.php`, `example2.php` and `example3.php`
- I am posting some values from `example1.php` to `example2.php` then I did all the DB stuff as per my need and rendered the page (Not Redirected - Just posted and the page got rendered).
- After that I have redirected the page from `example2.php` to `example3.php`.
  Now if you click browser back **Document will Expire**.

**To Avoid this we can post the values from `example1.php` to `example2.php` and redirect the user to some other page immediately.**

This is [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern that can be followed to avoid document expire. It also helps avoid redundant entry in DB.

Answer (score 5):

just put this line in your page.

```
<?php 
header("Cache-Control: max-age=300, must-revalidate"); 
?>
```

Comment: This worked on my hosted account when put in the php before building the html header.

Answer (score 2):

Go your server's php.ini and
change this

```
session.cache_limiter = nocache
```

As

```
 session.cache_limiter = public
```

The problem would be solved. I solved my problem with this.

Answer (score 1):

Check if caching is disabled on the header like

`<HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">`

Comment: OK, and if it is, what should I do?

Comment: you have to remove it. That should enable caching.

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through same problem. A page where I want to come back had posted values of form and so when I hit Back link, it was showing Document Expired error. See example-

There are three pages, page1.php, page2.php and page3.php. Now I am submitting some form from page1.php to page2.php using POST method. From page2.php I clicked some link of page3.php.

Now I want to come back on page2.php from page3.php. But page2.php have form values posted using POST method and when I come on page2.php from page3.php, browser showing error "Docuemnt Expired".

So I used **GET** method **instead** of **POST**. So when come back on page2.php, then there will not be POST values of form and page will load properly. Also, as form values are present in URL, it page will load as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This problem will arise by the following two scenarios:

- Implementing searching with `Post`
- Redirecting back to a page that was posted previously.

There are 2 ways to overcome this issue easily without any hack.

For `search form` do not use `post` method, instead use get method and everything works fine.

If you really need to hide the form inputs for whatever reason and want to use post method, then the link/action that causes the redirect to other page, make it redirect through JavaScript.

```
location.replace('http://example.com/page2');
```

This removes the referral URL and force a new http request.
Now pressing back button on browser wont cause the document expire.