# codeigniter multistage forms using POST and making the backbutton work

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, browser-cache, back

I have codeigniter forms which use POST to go from one page to the next. Each stage uses user submission data. I read in:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13559805/1021360

That I need to use a get-post-get method (GPG) in order to allow the back-button to work.

I have a lot of data in the session variable that is being tracked, the session is set to expire only when you go back to the home page or after 1 hour, so the back button should work. This is also where all of the core data is stored. (the POST is not all that relevant since the back page could just read it all back from the session, assuming I knew how to make the back button cache do so).

Currently backbutton results in an: "This document is no longer available." error page.

My views has a form with in it a call to a function called "/nextquestion".

this function does form validation, stores form values to the CI_session and then renders the next page if the form passes the validation check.

I am not sure how I would pass this to a third "file" (since codeigniter uses function calls, not php files) and then read it from it...?

All I'd like to achieve is that the back button works as it was intended: it should show you the previous page, the way it was rendered.

Any tips or help for how to get the browsers cache working well with codeigniter's form submissions would be most welcome!

Thanks.

Comment: The easiest would be to have all parts on one page and hide the other non active questions. However, in your case, what you could do is just have a link to the previous page /next page inside your view and the fact they are links means there will not be a refresh warning when you get to the page. You can also alternatively set the cache-control header to avoid refresh warning with the back button. example $this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: private");

Comment: show us your current codes.

Answer (score 1):

The way I generally do it is to submit the form to the same page, upon which I check if the $_POST array exists or not. If it doesn't exist then I assume the page hasn't been submitted and check for any data that may exist in the session.

The code for this would look something like this:

```
// Check if we have any post data (form was submitted or not)
if(count($_POST) > 0) {

    // Save post array to the session
    $this->session->set_userdata('post_data', $_POST );

    // Redirect to the same page (REMOVES POST FROM HTTP HEADERS)
    redirect('/form/page1','location');

} else {

    // There is no $_POST array, but we have the POST data in session 
    // I.E. RETURNING TO FORM VIA BACK BUTTON
    if($this->session->userdata('post_data')) {

        // Set POST array from session data
        $_POST = $this->session->userdata('post_data');

        // Clear the session
        $this->session->unset_userdata('post_data');
    }
}


// Your other code, validation rules, etc, etc

// VALIDATION FAILS - Validation fails
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

    // Load view
}

// VALIDATION SUCCEEDS - Proceed to confirmation  
else {
    redirect('/form/page2', 'location', 303);
}
```

Assuming the submitted data passes your validation rules, the general flow of the above would be:

- User browses to `/form/page1`, fills out and submits the form.
- The form is POSTED to itself, the $_POST array is saved to the session
- The user is then redirected to the same page, `/form/page1`, upon which the $_POST array is empty, and the POST header has been removed from the HTTP request.
- The $_POST array is then restored from the session data, and the form redirects to `/form/page2`. The user won't notice this step.
- Now, if the user presses the back button. There will be no error, because the previous page technically had no data posted to/from it.